# Mysql - checar ocorrência em todos os campos

Tags: mysql

Como checar a ocorrência de uma string em qualquer campo?

Nada especifico como `WHERE campo1 = "abcd"`, já que quero checar a ocorrência em qualquer campo.

que seja algo diferente também do extensivo OR, varrer cada campo, algo como : `WHERE campo1 = "abcd" OR campo2 = "abcd" OR campo3 = "abcd"`,..

Penso haver outra alternativa além desta ultima, sim?

Comment: Fala Alexandre, tudo bom? Olha, não sei se sou eu, mas fiquei meio perdido em sua dúvida, poderia nos explicar melhor?

Comment: Encontrei uma forma de fazer no Oracle, não sei da onde, mas eu pensei que era Oracle

Comment: @juniorb2ss Sim, ao invés de procurar no banco de dados em algum campo especifico, como `WHERE campo1 = 'valorqueeuprocuro'`, eu gostaria de procurar em todos os campos da minha tabela e não somente no campo1, sei que através do OR, eu posso ir repetindo essa mesma instrução para cada campo, mas isso deixaria a query grande, acredito que exista algum maneira simplificada.

Comment: Não é possível método global, porém existe algumas maneiras. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797906/mysql-query-for-searching-through-all-the-fields http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-of-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for possível utilizar uma linguagem de programação, essa tarefa não é tão complicada. A ideia é seguinte fazer duas consultas a primera pegando todos os campos de uma determinada tabela(talvez o tipo importe), depois na consulta principal fazer um `in() invertido` no lugar de passar valores para ele passe a lista de colunas.

Ex:

Retorna os nomes das colunas.

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'tabela'
```

A segunda consulta seria:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela where 'valor' IN(nome, email, endereco, outra_coluna)
```