# Como encontrar um termo num banco de dados mysql?

Tags: mysql

Como posso fazer uma busca em todos os campos de todas as tabelas de um determinado banco mysql? preciso encontrar uma palavra que não faço ideia de onde esteja.

No resultado precisaria do(s) nome(s) da(s) tabela(s) e o(s) nome(s) do(s) campo(s) onde o termo se encontra.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Ola, só em mysql?

Comment: No meu caso sim, mas se puder me explicar a lógica de como faz mesmo que seja em outro banco, fico grato...

Comment: Acredito que essa resposta pode ajudar, [checar ocorrência em todos os campos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86518/91). Só pode usar SQL? com um script de alguma linguagem pode simplificar algumas coisas. No pior dos casos vc pode escrever uma consulta que escreve outra com as informações dinâmicas.

Comment: Sim, no meu caso só a query pro banco que me serve.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122379/como-selecionar-todas-as-tabelas-que-contenham-o-campo-com-mesmo-nome

Answer (score 1):

Amigo,

Eu achei uma pessoa com a mesma dúvida que a sua. Dê uma olhada nesta resposta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562457/search-for-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-mysql-database#answer-26647118

Caso você não consiga, você poderia simplesmente fazer o download do seu database.sql e pesquisar no arquivo o termo que você quer. Esse seria o meio mais rápido, na minha opinião

Tem razão Thiago Luiz, vou colar a resposta que eu achei:

In **phpMyAdmin** a 'Search' feature is available:

1. Select particular database not table.
2. Click 'Search' tab
3. Enter the search term you want
4. Select the tables you want to search in

**phpMyAdmin** screen shot:

[image: phpMyAdmin Database Search tab]

The 'Search' feature is also available in **MySQL Workbench**:

1. Database Menu > Search Table Data
2. Select database and tables you want to search (it will search in selected tables only)
3. In search you can use wildChars.

**MySQL Workbench** screen shot:

[image: MySQL Workbench Database Search]