# Como selecionar todas as tabelas que contenham o campo com mesmo nome?

Tags: mysql, sql, relacionamento, dql, ddl

Preciso procurar todas os campos  "id_category" em um determinado banco de dados, e trazer uma lista das tabelas que contenham esse campo em comum, que no caso, é a chave estrangeira da tabela "sis_category".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma que resolvi isso, foi fazendo o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'meu_banco' and COLUMN_NAME='id_category';
```

E para trazer somente o nome da tabela:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'meu_banco' and COLUMN_NAME='id_category';
```

E para verificar os registros em cada uma das tabelas, executei a SQL abaixo:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * from ',TABLE_NAME),'
WHERE id_category=39;')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'meu_banco'
AND COLUMN_NAME='id_category'
```